# mock a database call which was written in a method with jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ts-jest

This is code I have and I want to test the method called getOrderData. Which will get the data from mongo db.

How can I mock this function?

orderCOntrollers.ts

```
    bunchOfOrders = async (req,res)=>{
            const id =req? req.id:{}; 
            let condition = {};
            if(common.isValid(id))
                condition = {_id:id}
            console.log("SAI",condition);
            const data = await orderService.getOrderData(condition);
            return response.send(req,res,data,"SUCCESS");
        }
```

app.test.js

```
        describe("Connecting To DB", () => {
            let mongoConnection;
            let sqlConnection;
            beforeAll(async () => {
                console.log("SAI @#")
                await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
                    useNewUrlParser: true,
                    useCreateIndex: true,
                    useUnifiedTopology: true,
                }).then(res => console.log("connected seccessfully"))
                    .catch("something error");
        test("checking an API", async () => {
                const res: any = await orderController.bunchOfOrders({}, {});
                expect(res.status).toBe(200)
        
            });
            });
```

Comment: As its mongodb, that should be tagged and not mysql. Does mocking the connection add value to the test?